# CORDOVA 3.4.0 3.4.1 - unable to generate an apk

Tags: android, cordova, ant

I'm trying to generate an apk from my **cordova application** with ant clean release.

I receive "cannot find symbol", here more detailed report:

http://dpaste.com/09HR9HW.txt

Tried with
cordova 3.4.0-0.1.3
and 3.4.1-0.1.0